# Gray box in ionic, outside of content and iOS wrapper on device orientation change

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Presently trying to figure out a strange display bug(?). Presently, in iOS emulation, a grey area appears outside of the app, filling a portion of the screen area between the app, and the expected iOS black.

I've applied crazy colors to any and every layer and element I can via the CSS. But that grey box seems to exist outside of the HTML container.

It's almost as if the grey is the expected position of the content while redrawing, while the actual content redrawing is lagging behind.

Since word's probably won't convey - here's a screen cap vid. It's a little more choppy than the actaul redraw I'm seeing. But you can see the grey era in question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cy9K2iJ0V9w

Thanks

Comment: Rather than a link to a video, can you not just take a screen shot and attach in-line?  Also, if you really want help, you best include the relevant code producing the part with the error.

Comment: Thanks Joe - I could do the screen shot or take a frame from the video cap. I just figured that a video gave better context is all.

Regarding the relevant code - well there in lies the problem. I don't know what the root cause of this is to even hope to post a relevant code segment.